# react-router-dom link takes time when it is clicked

Tags: hyperlink, react-router, react-router-dom

In create-react-app , why react-router-dom link takes some time and following warnings are displayed.how can we remove it
[Violation] 'click' handler took 899ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 103ms